# Can EFcore generated entities be used without a base class?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-2.0, clean-architecture

I'm trying to implement a Clean Architecture project from scratch following [Microsoft's ASP.NET architecture guidelines](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/web/aspnet-architecture) and their eShopOnWeb sample project.

The EF entities in my case are database first. For that, I've used the `Scaffold-DbContext` tool but it doesn't seem to allow specifying a base class for the generated entities. It wouldn't usually be a problem (I guess) but the eShopOnWeb project seems to have a `BaseEntity` superclass for all its entities.

My questions are -

1. Should I be worried about having all entities extending a base class at all? What if I just use the entities as-is (I'm somewhat new to this, so I might be missing something very basic)? In case, a base class is the right way to go, is there an "official" solution for generating entities with a predefined base class?
2. eShopOnWeb - Microsoft's official sample application - uses code first approach to db. Does that mean this is Microsoft's official recommendation as far as best practices are concerned? I'm a little wary of it because with that approach I'm not sure how database optimizations and fine-tuning (indexes and all other database specific stuff) etc could be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entities do not need to extend a base class. The only time I use them is in systems where I have truly common fields for some/most entities such as "EditableEntity" where I might put common fields like CreatedBy, CreatedAt, ModifiedBy, ModifiedAt, RowVersion. I don't use a base class for "Id" for example because often there are cases to use a different ID, or adopt a composite ID for certain tables.

Most examples out there use Code-First simply because it uses code to set up a schema, and that's what they expect developers to understand rather than SQL. IMO it's great for getting something up and running fast, but in the long-run I find it's more trouble than it's worth. (Messing around with tweaking migrations manually once you get to a point where DB data integrity is important.)  Personally I never use it because I came from a background that worked with SQL and ORMs before code-first so I'm more comfortable thinking about schema along-side code and using explicit mapping to ensure that I know exactly how EF will interpret that schema. It's good to understand how code-first and migrations work, but if you're comfortable with building schemas then DB-first is fine. The best practices come into play about learning how to map relationships and query the data efficiently. I.e. utilizing `.Select()` is probably the least understood aspect of fully leveraging Entity Framework.